# SharePoint workbench full width webpart but scss code dont work

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, workbench

I've added the CSS code, but it still doesn't use the whole page.

```
:global {
  #workbenchPageContent,
  .CanvasComponent.LCS .CanvasZone {
    max-width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using spfx to modify the global style may cause unexpected situations, so it is generally impossible to modify the global style
swap() {

```
const element = document.querySelector(".a_ai_ada2ac09 ") as HTMLElement;
if (element) {
  element.setAttribute("style", "pointer-events: none;"); // set  style  "pointer-events: none;"
}
```

}

Here is link about spfx:
https://www.bing.com/search?q=spfx+extension&form=ANNH01&refig=30225fa29c35447f8aac0ffadb74c581&sp=1&lq=0&qs=MT&pq=spfx+ex&sc=10-7&cvid=30225fa29c35447f8aac0ffadb74c581

[image]